# xaml UI is not updating in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am binding my model with my UI and in my model i have done some  calculation but other properties are binding with UI but some properties in which i have done calculation these are not binding with my UI but showing the calculation in my OnPropertyChange event.Kindly help me on this where is issue on my codes  Thanks in advance.

-----My model----

```
 public class SaleEntryModel 
  {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]

    public int SaleID { get; set; }

    
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
           
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public decimal Total => Rate * Quantity;

    public decimal Balance => (Total - (Discount + PaidAmount));

}
```

-- I am calculating the total and balance from the rate and quantity properties---

----OnPropertyChange event ---

```
    private SaleEntryModel bindSaleEntryModel = new SaleEntryModel();

    public SaleEntryModel BindSaleEntryModel
    {
        get { return bindSaleEntryModel; }
        set
        {
            bindSaleEntryModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindSaleEntryModel));
        }
    }
```

---my xaml code ---

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10">

       
            <Label  Text="Rate" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />


            <Entry x:Name="Rate" Margin="2,-5,2,5" Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.Rate,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next" />

            <Label x:Name="RateError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Quantity" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="Quantity"  Margin="2,-5,2,5" Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.Quantity,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next" />
            <Label x:Name="QuantityError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Total" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="Total" Margin="2,-5,2,5" IsEnabled="False"
                   Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.Totals,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ReturnType="Next"/>

            <Label Text="Discount (Rs)" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="Discount" Margin="2,-5,2,5" Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.Discount,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                   Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next"/>
            <Label x:Name="DiscountError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Paid Amount" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="PaidAmount" Margin="2,-5,2,5" Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.PaidAmount,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Keyboard="Numeric" ReturnType="Next"/>
            <Label x:Name="PaidAmountError" Margin="2,-10,2,5" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="false" FontAttributes="Italic" />

            <Label Text="Balance" Margin="2,-10" FontAttributes="Bold" />

            <Entry x:Name="Balance"  Margin="2,-5,2,5" IsEnabled="False"
                   Text="{Binding BindSaleEntryModel.Balance,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

            
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Text="Save" x:Name="btnSave" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#ff6633" TextColor="#fff" Margin="2" 
                        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />

                <Button Text="CLEAR" x:Name="btnClear" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        CornerRadius="10" BorderWidth="2" BackgroundColor="#bfbfbf" 
                        TextColor="#fff" Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}" />
            </Grid>


        </StackLayout>
```

[image: OnPropertyChange debug]

In above image calculation is showing but not binding in My UI.

Comment: SaleEntryModel needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: apply INotifyPropertyChanged  in SaleEntryModel also ?

Comment: yes, if that class contains the properties that you want to dynamically update, then that class should implement INPC and those properties should raise PropertyChanged events

Comment: i have also used INPC like this                                                                            
    private SaleEntryModel bindSaleEntryModel = new SaleEntryModel();       

    public SaleEntryModel BindSaleEntryModel
    {
        get { return bindSaleEntryModel; }
        set
        {
            bindSaleEntryModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindSaleEntryModel));
        }
    }

Comment: please do not post code in comments, it is very difficult to read.

Comment: u see on my code above i have alrady used on INPC event in viewmodel so do i need a another in my salenetrymode class also ?

Comment: Yes.  I have already told you that TWICE.  This is the THIRD time.

Comment: thanks for your kindly support

Comment: @jason i have tried but it does not work for me

Comment: I have no way of knowing what you've actually done if you don't update your post with the new code.  Hint: when Rate or Quantify changes, you need to fire a property changed event for Total.  Otherwise the UI will not know that Total has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need raise property change for each binding property in SaleEntryModel. Please refer following code.

```
 public partial class CalculationQ : ContentPage
    {
        public CalculationQ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            GetSaleEntry();
        }

        private SaleEntryModel bindSaleEntryModel = new SaleEntryModel();
        public SaleEntryModel BindSaleEntryModel
        {
            get { return bindSaleEntryModel; }
            set
            {
                bindSaleEntryModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BindSaleEntryModel));
            }
        }

        private void GetSaleEntry()
        {
            BindSaleEntryModel.SaleID = 1;
            BindSaleEntryModel.CustomerName = "Murugan";
            BindSaleEntryModel.ProductID = 1;
            BindSaleEntryModel.ProductName = "Toy";
            BindSaleEntryModel.Quantity = 5;
            BindSaleEntryModel.Rate = 150;
            BindSaleEntryModel.Discount = 5;
            BindSaleEntryModel.PaidAmount = 250;
        }

    }

    public class SaleEntryModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public int SaleID { get; set; }

        private string _customerName;
        public string CustomerName
        {
            get { return _customerName; }
            set
            {
                _customerName = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(CustomerName));
            }
        }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        private string _productName;
        public string ProductName
        {
            get { return _productName; }
            set
            {
                _productName = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(ProductName));
            }
        }

        private decimal _quantity;
        public decimal Quantity
        {
            get { return _quantity; }
            set
            {
                _quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Quantity));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Total));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Balance));
            }
        }

        private decimal _rate;


        public decimal Rate
        {
            get { return _rate; }
            set
            {
                _rate = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Rate));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Total));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Balance));
            }
        }

        public decimal Total => Rate * Quantity;

        public decimal Balance => (Total - (Discount + PaidAmount));

        private int _discount;
        public int Discount
        {
            get => _discount;
            set
            {
                _discount = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Discount));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Balance));
            }
        }

        private int _paidAmount;
        public int PaidAmount
        {
            get => _paidAmount;
            set
            {
                _paidAmount = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(PaidAmount));
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(Balance));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChange(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

    }
```

My suggestion is to keep separate model for viewmodel binding instead of using entity model.

Comment: thanks for your reply i have implemented above mention code and it is working.