# How can I bind to a property value within a an object in a grouped list

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

First off, thankyou for the solution to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73108557/how-can-i-display-a-list-of-objects-within-a-list-of-objects-with-a-multi-value)

That solution works very well, however, i'm struggling to bind the change of one of the properties. I have the BackgroundColour binding well when the UI loads with the following code:
**UI View**

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stlShippingOrders" Spacing="5" Padding="0,0,0,5" >
        <CollectionView Margin="0,-6,0,0" IsGrouped="True" ItemsSource="{Binding 
ShippingItems}">
            <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5,-5,5,-5" Orientation="Horizontal" 
BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HeightRequest="45">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.OrderCode}" 
VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.CustomerName}" 
VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Shipment.DeliveryDate}" 
HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Padding="5,2,5,2" Text="{Binding ItemDescription}" 
BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColour}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

**ShippingItem Model (with added BacgroundColour property)**

```
 public class ShippingItem
{
    public String ShippingItemId { get; set; }
    public string ShippingItemScanCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string ShippingOrderId { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

    // Default set to transparent #00FFFFFF
    public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }  = "#00FFFFFF";

}
```

**Class for grouping**

```
public class ShippingItemGroup : ObservableCollection<ShippingItem>
{
    public ShippingOrder Shipment { get; private set; }

    public ShippingItemGroup(ShippingOrder shipment, ObservableCollection<ShippingItem> 
shippingItems) : base(shippingItems)
    {
        Shipment = shipment;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel code that creates the group list and binds correctly**

```
                        public ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup> ShippingItems { 
get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup>();
                    foreach (var item in thisShipment.ShippingOrders)
                    {
                        ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItemGroup(item, 
item.ShippingItems));
                    }
```

**ViewModel code that updates the list object when it is loaded.
This is the bit i'm having trouble with, the shippingItem.BackgroundColour = "FFA533" changes the collection but doesn't update the UI.**

```
foreach (ShippingItemGroup shippingItemGroup in ShippingItems)
                    {
                        foreach(ShippingItem shippingItem in 
shippingItemGroup.Shipment.ShippingItems)
                        {
                            if(shippingItem.ShippingItemScanCode == scanCode)
                            {
                                shippingItem.IsLoaded = true;
                                shippingItem.BackgroundColour = "FFA533";
                                IsShipmentHeaderVisible = true;
                                IsShippingOrdersVisible = true;
                                IsErrorMessageVisible = false;
                                ScanCode = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: ShippingItem needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Thanks Jason, I did try and add a getter and setter to ShippingItem with that called OnPropertyChanged from the baseViewModel but it failed at the OnPropertyChanged event.

Comment: did you actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?  Just calling `OnPropertyChanged` is not sufficient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xaml UI is not updating in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821777/xaml-ui-is-not-updating-in-xamarin-forms). Or for dozens of similar questions, google `site:stackoverflow.com xamarin forms binding ui does not update`.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else coming to this question. The question has been marked as closed because there was already an existing answer on another question. However, that answer relies on using the built in PropertyChanged event of ContentPage. This is not applicable to this question because INotifyPropertyChanged needed to be implemented on a class that did not inherit from ContentPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason mentioned in the comments, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. This is the way I've done it for other projects. This is adapted from how MVVMCross does it.

First, create a base class where the INotifyPropertyChanged logic is setup:

```
public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        return true;
    }
}
```

This will handle setting the value and firing the PropertyChanged event.

Next, have whatever model you need inherit from this base class. In this, it's your ShippingItem class:

```
public class ShippingItem : ModelBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ShippingOrderId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

    private string backgroundColor;
    public string BackgroundColor
    {
        get => backgroundColor;
        set => SetProperty(ref backgroundColor, value);
    }
}
```

Note the addition of the private backgroundColor field, and the custom setter that calls the SetProperty in the base class.

This will handle the updates for you.

I modified the code from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111986/8395242) just as a proof of concept. This will update the colors every 1.5 seconds:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var shipment = new Shipment();

    foreach (var item in shipment.ShippingOrders)
    {
        ShippingItems.Add(new ShippingItemGroup(item, item.ShippingItems));
    }

    BindingContext = this;

    var rnd = new Random();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            foreach (var shippingItemGroup in ShippingItems)
            {
                foreach (var shippingItem in shippingItemGroup)
                {
                   shippingItem.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256)).ToHex();
                }
            }
       }
    });
}

public ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup> ShippingItems { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<ShippingItemGroup>();
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that. I had just been calling OnPropertyChanged without properly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged as suggested by @Jason. Thanks both.